# TYPO3 + dmailsubscription: Get a confirmation message after email for editing profile

Tags: typo3, subscription, newsletter

Im using dmailsubscription to register users to a newsletter. Theres an option where, once already registered and confirmed, you can get an email with the link to edit your profile.

The problem is, once you enter the email address, the page is reloaded and the plugin shows no message at all. Id like to get some sort of confirmation text, like:

"The email with the link to edit your profile was sent to xxx@xxx.com"

or at least:

"The email with the link to edit your profile was sent to your email address"

, but I dont know how.

Here's my template: http://pastebin.com/K5WVSgrY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Above**

```
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_DELETE_SAVED### begin
```

But **AFTER**

```
###TEMPLATE_INFOMAIL### end-->
```

Try to add this:

```
<BR><BR><BR><BR>
<HR>
<BR><BR><BR><EM>This template is the response page when a users has requested 
his password send to his email.</EM> <BR><BR><!-- ###TEMPLATE_INFOMAIL_SENT### begin
    This template is the response page when a users has requested his password send to his email.
-->###GW1B###We have emailed your your details. Edit your message here.###GW1E###<BR><BR>###GW2B### <A 
href="http://www.yourdomain.ext/###BACK_URL###"><STRONG>Go back</STRONG></A><BR>###GW2E### 
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_INFOMAIL_SENT### end--><BR><BR><BR><BR>
<HR>
```

I cannot find this part in your template-file.